# Why does $\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-1}$ have only one asymptote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I want to find the asymptotes of the function

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-1}$.

I feel like I am missing something here... But I understand that the denominator should factor out into $(x+1)(x-1)$ and therefore return two asymptotes. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Please format your questions in MathJax.

Comment: Uhm, this function has actually two asymptotes, not one

Comment: @imranfat Yes, but I think the OP believes that there are two *vertical asymptotes*, not a vertical asymptote and a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Yes I was referring to vertical asymptotes. Thanks.

Comment: In this new MSE format, I did not get a pop up indicating that there was a message for me, that's strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator factors and cancels with one of the factors in the denominator:

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x-3)(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}=\frac{x-3}{x+1}$.

Hence, we have a vertical asymptote at $x=-1$ and a hole in the graph at $x=1$. Then we have a horizontal asymptote at $y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

While I would like to echo what has already been said, namely that the function can be written as
$$f(x) = \frac{(x-3)(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)},$$
it is *not* true that $$f(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+1}$$
as has been mentioned because in the first equation $x=1$ is not in the domain and in the second equation $x=1$ is in the domain.  Technically the cancellation can happen except for at $x = 1$, where it should be noted that the function remains undefined.  Therefore $$f(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+1}\quad (x\neq 1)$$ is the appropriate simplification.  A subtle distinction, yes, but an important one.  What that tells us is that $x = -1$ is a vertical asymptote and at $x = 1$ there will be a hole in the graph.  In fact, by plugging in $x = 1$ to $\frac{x-3}{x+1}$ we can see where the point would be, so the graph has a hole at the point .$(1,-1)$

Comment: That is an important distinction, though I think it is a bit beyond the scope of a pre-calc class, as they just cancel things all the time without domain worries. I don't think that the domain is stressed, though I agree that it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator factors out into $(x-1)(x-3)$ so the function can be simplified into $$\frac{x-3}{x+1}.$$